# Xcode 4.3.2 adhoc signing entitlements (0xE8008016)

Tags: ios, xcode4, distribution, ad-hoc-distribution, code-signing-entitlements

I'm having this problem I need to build an adhoc build for each of a 3 application. I always used this feature and never had a problem. After building the project I use the organizer to send it to the device, but unfortunately it shows me this message:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning
>   profile.
>
> (0xE8008016).

I made different searches and applied all the possible solutions, but it doesn't work. 
I've tried to restore the device, to recreate certificates, profiles etc... but no way.
Only one of those app is able to be installed, but nothing in build settings seems to be different from the others. 
 The entitlements in the profile seems correct.

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>DCQ6Z436Z4.it.xxxxx.*</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>DCQ6Z436Z4.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: make sure your profile has been loaded via the Organizer. That mistake drove me crazy for an afternoon...

Comment: Hi Paul. yes it is, and I also have nice green check on their side

Comment: drat, hoped it was that easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is turning out to be a kind of a weird bug of Xcode.
Here is the explanation. The project was made using xcode 3, in xcode 3 to create an adhoc build was necessary to create another buld settings. Since xcode 4 came out I never used that scheme anymore, I used to archive with the distribution profile and later distribute/share with the ad-hoc prov profile. This method seems to be broken if you have another old scheme as I had and because the app seems to be certified with only the final distrib profile. The fix was to set also the "release" version to use the adhoc profile and now everything seems to work fine.
 Hope this helps.